# Can't tweet from Python despite elevated access

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have the following function:

```
import tweepy

def tweet_message(text):
    # Replace these with your own API key and secret
    api_key = API_KEY
    api_secret = API_KEY_SECRET
    access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN
    access_token_secret = ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET

    # Authenticate with Twitter API
    auth = OAuthHandler(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    # Tweet the text
    api.update_status(status=text)
```

I am using Tweepy to post tweets via Python.

I have elevated access developer account and I have all of the following keys:

```
API_KEY = '...'
API_KEY_SECRET = '...'
BEARER_TOKEN = '...'
CLIENT_ID = '...'
CLIENT_SECRET = '...'
ACCESS_TOKEN = '...'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '...'
```

But when I run the function, I get this error:

```
TweepError: [{'code': 220, 'message': 'Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.'}]
```

Where am I going wrong? My credentials should allow access to it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using api keys to authenticate but you should be using user access tokens.

`statuses/update` is an API that you (as the app owner) call on behalf of the user. To be able to do this, you need to [authenticate](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/overview) the user and call the API using the access tokens that you got from Twitter for that user.

Comment: Where can I get the user access tokens?

Comment: You can look at the Twitter documentation I linked. You need to perform the the 3-legged OAuth flow to get the acess tokens: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens

Comment: I found it but how do I use the user access tokens with Tweepy? Such as in the function in my post?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/authentication.html

Comment: No because `AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'OAuth1UserHandler'`